# What word did Middle English have in place of “light" as in: “light blue”, “light green” etc.?

Tags: etymology, early-modern-english, shakespeare, colors

In English, we often use the adjective ***light*** before another colour to express a *whiter* shade of hue. For example, *light blue*, *light green*, *light brown*, etc. 
The term ***pale*** is used in a similar way, e.g.; *pale grey*, *pale yellow*, and *pale red*.

Etymonline dates this usage of *[**light**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=light&allowed_in_frame=0)*:

> **light (adj.2)** (see **[light](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=light&allowed_in_frame=0)** (n.)). Meaning "pale-hued" is from **1540s**.

and for ***[pale](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pale&allowed_in_frame=0)*** early **1300s**

> **pale (adj.)** early 14c., from Old French *paile* "pale, light-colored" (12c., Modern French *pâle*), from Latin *pallidus* "pale, pallid, wan, colorless," from *pallere* "be pale, grow pale,"

If we look at names for “light blue”, only *azure* predates Early Modern English

- **azure**  early 14c., from Old French *azur*, *asur*, a color name...
- **sky blue**  is said to have first appeared in print in 1704

  > A Collection of Voyages and Travels (London: Awnsham and John Churchill, 1704), vol. 2, p. 322, where John Nieuhoff describes certain flowers: "they are of a lovely sky blue colour, and yellow in the middle" <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_blue)</sub>
- **cyan** (originally called *[cyan-blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyan)*) meaning ‘light blue’ is dated 1879

To illustrate my point more clearly, here is a Google [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=light%20blue%2Clight%20red%2Clight%20green%2Clight%20brown&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clight%20blue%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clight%20red%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clight%20green%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clight%20brown%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Clight%20blue%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Clight%20red%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Clight%20green%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Clight%20brown%3B%2Cc1) set at British English, which suggests that the combination, *light* + *name of colour*, began from mid 17th century.

[image: Ngram chart]

---

**Questions**

- How did Middle and Early Modern English speakers say that a colour was *light*?
- Did they place  term *white* before a colour; e.g. *whit blewe* (white blue)?
- What does *[whyte russet](https://books.google.it/books?id=IKTFAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT384&lpg=PT384&dq=%22whyte%20russet%22&source=bl&ots=gl5Xv3GEXy&sig=nrmG5-BaiPnFfSaFtidBv_0vBvQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpoJbspcrNAhUC2CwKHbIZD4YQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22whyte%20russet%22&f=false)* mean? Is it a ‘pale reddish-brown’?

Comment: I suspect that the answer to this question would depend on  the color technology  (paints/dyes) and the local environment of the culture.  Thus, shades of blue, for example, would probably be described by something in nature that they resembled (sky, robin's egg) or by the animal/mineral/vegetable extract used to make a pigment for paints or fabric dyes. ("Light" or "dark" may not have been an important factor in the description.)

Comment: Related: [Where did the term “strawberry blonde” come from?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/280065/where-did-the-term-strawberry-blonde-come-from)

Comment: Was there any particular motivation that got you to ask this question? Like, were you casually reading Chaucer, as one does, and saw the word 'blue' and wondered how he would have said 'light blue'? You do realize that a legitimate answer was 'They didn't bother'. For example, what is the term that Middle English have for 'indigo'? It was probably just 'purple' since Newton came up with the term indigo himself (for some intermediate shade of purple). Also, for clarification, are you looking for a systematic construction or is one 'light' word for each color OK?

Comment: No, @Mitch I never read Chaucer, Piers Plowman, or the William Tyndale Bible. The first two are incomprehensible to me. I was merely struck to discover that expressions I took for granted, such as *light blue*, *light red* and *light green* did not seem to have existed prior to Shakespeare or, if you prefer, the 1600s. I do not consider, "They didn't bother", to be a legitimate answer, but you're free to post it if that is what you think.

Comment: I'm surprised that you'd think 'no answer' is not a legitimate answer. Some languages have only 3 color terms. You're asking a question like 'how did a language which only has a word for the range red-to-yellow say red?' The point is they just don't. So I'm not sure what is an acceptable answer. Also, what is 'light'? Less saturated in an HSV model. 'Bright' sounds like _more_ saturated to me.

Comment: [Basic Colour Categories](http://wals.info/chapter/133) from World Atlas of Language Structure

Comment: @Mitch the question is limited to the English language.  What does the link tell me how the English communicated different shades of colour in medieval England? But I think you are right about *bright*, maybe in the 15th century it had a different meaning when it was attached to a colour.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's an analogy. As similar as it may seem, ME is a different language. What they mean by particular words is closely related to how we mean them but not necessarily the same. What did people call pink before there was a word pink, or orange before orange? There's no guarantee that people said anything at all for those. In some of these foreign lanuages theres is a word that works for what we call both red and yellow. They have no word for just red or just yellow. They just say 'this kind of red-yellow, the one that looks like blood' or 'that kind of r-y, that looks like dandelions'

Comment: @Mitch go ahead post that as an answer. I posted something because I waited for the experts. No one came forward. I don't think English in 1400 was unrecognizable to speakers in the 1600, that's not how language works, but definitely in ME there are obsolete expressions and turn of phrases and I'm sure many apply to colour terms. But... blue, whether it is spelled *blew*, or *blu* still refers to a specific shade, and we can verify this in art. An artist who painted between 1300 -1400, used paints which had names, the same names that artists use today e.g.  burnt sienna, scarlet,  ochre etc.

Comment: Worth a look: http://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/colour.htm

Comment: @Josh61 thanks, it's an excellent link.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you could use Fair, Fade or Faint (there might be others)

> **Fair**

and its other forms

> fair (adj.) Also (early) faȝer, faier, fei(e)r, vair, fare, fer(e,
>   war, fæger, fægerra, fægrost

According to the Middle English dictionary from [Umich](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=53436130&egdisplay=compact&egs=53454449)

> (a) Light, bright, or shining (as opposed to dark); (b) of persons:
>   light of complexion or color of hair and eyes; fair.

It seems to have been  used with color (other than applied to skin or complexion):

Found at least one reference as cited in  Altenglische legenden ...
Horstmann, Carl, ed. b. 1851.

> [þat þis on schal beo **fair blu** cloth](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme?didno=AFY7823.0001.001;rgn=full%20text;size=25;sort=occur;start=1;subview=detail;type=simple;view=reslist;q1=fair)

...

> [**Faint**](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=54813163&egdisplay=open&egs=54830019)
>
> Of things, actions, functions, etc.: weak, feeble; impaired, poor;
>   pale **(color)**...

...

> **Fade**
>
> Of color or things having color: lacking in brilliance; pale,
>   discolored, dim; dull; **fade-heued**.

(Fade-heued meaning "light-colored")

[>c1300 SLeg.Mich.(LdMisc 108)   672:  Ho-so hath of þe eorþe mest, he is..Of fade [vr. vad] colur.](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=53222476&egdisplay=open&egs=53224578)

...

As for your example of **"whyte Russet"** I think russet is used here in the sense of

> ["a serviceable woolen cloth, usu. of plain or subdued color & usu.
>   worn by the poor or by workingmen (also by the Duke of Suffolk as a
>   sea-cloak)"](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED38155)

the same way Whites can be used for "clothes usually of white color" in modern sense, Russet is used by analogy for the piece of cloth *usually of the color Russet* or the *fabric material* itself with which one makes russets.

See [here](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme?didno=ACA1723.0001.001;rgn=full%20text;size=25;sort=occur;start=1;subview=detail;type=simple;view=reslist;q1=russet) in *The Stonor letters and papers, 1290-1483; ed. for the Royal historical society, from the original documents in the Public record office*, by Charles Lethbridge Kingsford, for **Russet** used with the color Black, for example, in the sense of piece of cloth or fabric material.

> a ȝerde off blake russet karyssey to make Richert Baron a dublet
>
> a payre off hosyn off russet karyssey,
>
> Item a gowne of russet furryd wt blakke,

another example of russet used in the sense of fabric.

> [And is as gladde of a goune · of a graye russet /](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme?didno=AJT8124.0001.001;rgn=full%20text;size=25;sort=occur;start=1;subview=detail;type=simple;view=reslist;q1=russet)

So the answer is I don't think **whyte russet** mean a light russet (color).

Answer (score 4):

From about 1300 is [Lenten ys come with loue to toune](http://www.southampton.ac.uk/%7Ewpwt/harl2253/lenten/lenttext.htm)
([alternative source](https://books.google.com/books?id=viFAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=%22lyhte%20wode%22%20light&source=bl&ots=elBY70E-3Y&sig=ZDnlQmgGxriMDwnTRF_Z17XarWE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSurTxt_3NAhUKxGMKHbfMB1wQ6AEIMjAD#v=onepage&q=%22lyhte%20wode%22%20light&f=false))

> The rose rayleth hire rode;
> The leues on the lyhte wode
> Waxen al with wille.

which has been translated as:

> The rose begins to blush;
> The leaves in the light-green wood
> All unfurl gladly.

Other translations exist such as [that of Aniee Jeong](http://eng205.aineejeong.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/My-Translation.png)

An early modern English example is from [Parthenophil and Parthenophe. Sonnettes, Madrigals, Elegies and Odes](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A04567.0001.001/1:6.13?rgn=div2;view=fulltext)

> There in amantle of **light greene**,
> Reseru'd by custome for that day
> *Parthenophe* they did aray
> And did create her sommers Queene,
> And ruler of their merrie may.

[Barnabe Barnes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnabe_Barnes), May 1593.

Comment: Your source for the last example gives modernised spelling.  The original spelling is available online from the [EEBOTCP](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A04567.0001.001/1:6.13?rgn=div2;view=fulltext): *“There in amantle of light greene, //
Reseru'd by custome for that day //
Parthenophe they did aray //
And did create her sommers Queene, //
And ruler of their merrie may.”*  (I guess the missing space in *amantle* is a transcription error, but I’m not sure.)

Comment: @PLL , thanks, I changed my answer to what you said.

Answer (score 2):

Etymonline is wrong; *light* has been used to modify color words long before the 1540s. To supplement @[DavePHD's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/337864/466641), here are a few more examples courtesy of a Middle English dictionary creatively titled, *[Middle English Dictionary](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Middle_English_Dictionary/i3xYTmwQ7zkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA1011&printsec=frontcover)*:

> - "Ʒelouʒ colour [of urine] & melky..tokeneþ feblenes of hete..& **liʒt red** [L subrufus] tokeneþ mene." -  [1398, Middle English translation of *Bartholomaeus's De Proprietatibus Rerum*]
> - "pannis integris de **lyghtgrene**" -  [1420, *Account Rolls of the Abbey of Durham*]
> - "peciæ de **light blew** and sade blew operatæ." -  [1449, *Testamenta Eboracensia*]
> - "Periot is stone þat is **lyʒt grene**" - [1500, *Lapidary in Peterborough 33*]

And here's [one I found in Chaucer](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/43016/43016-h/43016-h.htm) [late 14th-century], modifying *[watchet](https://www.wordsense.eu/watchet/)* (a shade of blue):

> Y-clad he was ful smal and proprely, al in a kirtel of a **liht wachet** — ful faire and thikke been the poyntes set.

Answer (score -1):

Even today, there's confusion regarding color terminology. The idea of "light blue" could refer to the hue called "blue" with lots of white added to it (that's often referred to in the context of prints and dyes as "a tint of blue" (just as by adding black to a hue, one produces various "shades of blue").

However, the idea of "light blue" might also embrace the idea of adding the complement of blue (that color lying 180-degrees apart from the specified color on a color wheel), which "desaturates" the hue, and brings it incrementally closer to gray.

Thus, to lighten a color, or to make it paler, could mean (without more restrictive definitions) adding white to produce a tint, or adding the complement, in order to desaturate it.

The Munsell System of color identification specified three metrics, or "dimensions," of color: hue, value, chroma. "Hue" is the name of the pure color by its family name (blue, red, green, etc.). "Value" is how light the hue is in terms of tinting and shading (represented along a vertical axis, with pure white at the north pole, and pure black at the south). "Chroma" referred to the saturation or purity of a hue. The pure hue was represented on the "equator" of a sphere, with progressively less saturated, or "grayer," versions of the hue appearing as it moved toward the central Value axis.

The Pantone System of color-matching appeared after Munsell (a painter by profession) did his classification, but uses similar dimensions, which I remember as being Hue, Brightness, and Saturation.

The above comments on color assume the subtractive model of color production; i.e., colors as it pertains to paints, pigments, dyes, and semi-opaque filters of glass, plastic, etc.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? Your answer doesn't seem to be about Middle English (or Early Modern English) terminology at all.

Comment: Has to do with what someone in the days of Middle English or Early Modern English actually meant by "Light Blue" or "Pale Blue." Might not be what we mean by those terms.

Comment: You mean 20th century English (when the Pantone and Munsell systems were created)? Do you have any other sources for the information in your post?

Comment: Any standard book on color theory and its history. Since we moderns don't always know what is meant by "light blue" (a higher value of blue? a lower chroma of blue? which?) then we couldn't possibly know what someone in the Middle Ages meant by it. It becomes a translation problem.